# Finding a cycle in graph theory.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if every vertex of a simple graph G has degree at least 2 then G contains a cycle. ( our definition says no multiple edges and no loops allowed also all simple graphs are finite by our Def'n)

Originally i tried to simply pick a vertex at random say $v_0$ then move away from it at random deleting each edge as i traversed it i made the assumption that eventually i would arrive back to a vertex that i had already been at and i would have a circuit. 
Then if this vertex i landed on a second time was $v_0$ i am done and have a cycle.   If it is not a cycle i wished to delete the edge $v_0v_1$ where $v_1$ was the first vertex i moved to and proceed in this fashion until whatever vertex i started on i also ended on then claim that this was in fact a cycle.

For some reason that i dont understand this doesn't actually work.

Any ideas how to solve this would much appreciated.

Comment: Your graoh has to be finite for this to have any chance of being true.

Comment: What leads you to conclude that it "doesn't actually work"?

Comment: My prof said it didn't work i dont even know why it doesn't work =(
Something about having things of degree 1 after i left the first vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method of random walking should discover a cycle in a finite simple graph of minimum degree $2$, although it may not include the starting vertex.

Eventually, because there only a finite number of edges, you will reach a point where no further steps are possible. At that point you have arrived at a vertex that you visited previously. The portion of the route from your previous visit to that vertex and the end point is a cycle.

Restarting the process is unnecessary, though; continuously following edges (without using any edge twice) until there are no possible next steps is sufficient.

[image]

Here the initial node $1$ is not part of any cycle but the walk ends at the vertex here marked $3$, so $3{-}4{-}5{-}6$ is the cycle discovered.

Comment: thats what i thought :s

Comment: @Faust7 Possible your prof thought you were claiming that the original vertex was in that cycle, which is not at all guaranteed. There may well be vertices in such a graph that are not on any cycle.

Comment: is there anthor simple way to solve it?